# Can you continue a non-steam save in the steam version of the game?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

If you're playing a regular installed copy of *Dragon Age: Origins*, and then you purchase the Steam copy, can you continue with the same character/save game?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your saves and character data is stored in the `My Documents\Bioware\Dragon Age\Characters` folder.

Inside that, there should be a folder with the name of your character, and inside that, a `saves` folder.

If you copy that folder to a back-up location, then uninstall your previous copy, and install the Steam version, you can then copy it back to the same location and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

i think the save games are stored in the Documents\Bioware both for the steam and regular version

you can make a backup of that folder and experiment :)